# Mysql ODBC 5.3 Driver Crash when hitting Test

Tags: mysql, dns, odbc, ssms, mysql-connector

I'm pretty new to Mysql, so here is my first question. Sorry for my bad english.

I would like to create a Linked Server Connection between my SQL Server 2008 and MYSQL-Server.
However, everytime I try to create an ODBC DSN (Either System-DNS or User-DNS), it crashes after I hit the "Test"-Button. I use Mysql ODBC 5.3 Driver, and it doesnt matter if I use the ANSI or UNICODE version. The Mysql Environment is on a Lamp-Server.
I didnt try reinstallation yet, maybe one of you can give me a hint or something.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with the mariadb ODBC V1.0 Driver.
Using the MySQL ODBC 5.3.1 Driver solved the problem.